# How to start Blackberry 10 development

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I am trying to learn Blackberry development on QNX Momentics IDE. I have searched for good video tutorials. Does anyone have some good step by step guides that I can follow? Getting the sample apps have not really helped me because I do not understand the code yet, hence the need tutorials for good guidance. I'm looking for something similar to "MyBringBack" for `Android`, but obviously I have not found anything yet. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Some good examples are here: http://www.bbcascades.com/

Comment: @BojanKogoj +1 for comment. Thank you, I will use all the help I can get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does look like a good starting point: http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/getting_started/

If you insist on video material you could take a look at their YouTube channel:
http://www.youtube.com/blackberrydev/

Answer (score 0):

Here's BlackBerry offical Web Training for Cascades & WebWorks

[BlackBerry Builder Web-Based Training](https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberrybuilders/prepare/web_training.html)

also [BlackBerry Support Forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com) are very useful

Hope this help. Reach me on twitter @kemobyte if you need any help.

Comment: also find our repo at Github https://github.com/blackberry/
it has alot of samples created by BB & Other BB developers.